# Build facebook app and get access to user profile

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook

Well developing of facebook app looks unclear because of fb is changing very fast.

My question about to get app access to user's profile.

1. I can to use login button inside app simular to website.
2. I can show to user access permission dialog box.
3. I can nothing to do but then i could only to get access to user public information(what is it? Only basic profile info? Can i to get friends list or wall posts?).

Is it right?

Is there good ACTUAL examples of FB application on asp.net mvc?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there good ACTUAL examples of FB application on asp.net mvc?

Yes, there's a good one here:

https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-canvas-aspnet-sample